# SSHFS: get real pwd on original server?

Tags: sshfs, pwd

I have connected one of my production server folders with my "ssh account" server via `sshfs`.

I often need to find out `pwd` (or `realpath`) of the file on the original (production) server, but the pwd returns the path to file on the connected ("ssh account") server.

Is there a way to get original path?

Thanks

Edit: more about this: I am using this to link my ssh server to multiple different SFTP servers/shared hosting.

so, if i do this (on some of the servers): `sshfs user@domain:/ mount_point`, then I am connected to my FTP account, which acts as root for my user, but is more along something like `/var/www/clients/c/a/account/pub/` and that's the path I need –

```
sshfs user@domain:/ mount_point # mount SFTP acc.
cd mount_point
XXXX file.ext # get back: /var/www/clients/…/pub/file.ext
pwd file.ext # returns /ssh-server/path/mount_point/file.ext
```

Hope it makes sense now.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get from readlink -f <file> ?

Comment: `/ssh-account/path/to/file`… the wrong one

Comment: If your `sshd` on the server is run in a chroot such that its `/` is not the actual `/` on the server and you want that actual `/`, there is no way to get the actual `/` on the server via ssh. You could, however, still define an alias as suggested in my answer and simply replace the `/var/www/mywebsite` accordingly (for example, use `/var/www/clients/c/a/account/pub` or so). In order not to define multiple aliases, you could parse the output of `mount`, decide where this actually points to using the username given to `sshfs` and then build the output accordingly.

Comment: @Claudius wow, I hoped there is something like `pwd --see-through-every-mount-and-symlink` :D

Comment: `pwd --blatantly-defy-chroot --ignore-filesystem-restrictions --find-absolutely-the-absolute --accept-no-substitutes --never-surrender` ?

Comment: yeah… talk about looking for unicorn

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path mounted via sshfs from the output of `mount` (or simply remember it). Then you can either

- build an alias that takes a path on the client, removes the mountpoint of the SSHfs and prepends the original name of the directory on the server. For example, if you mount the remote directory `/var/www/mywebsite` locally to `/home/test/website` (`sshfs server:/var/www/mywebsite /home/test/website`), then the following will work:

  ```
  $ alias mpwd="pwd | sed 's|^/home/test/website|/var/www/mywebsite|'"
  $ pwd
  /home/test/website
  $ mpwd
  /var/www/mywebsite
  $ cd gallery
  $ mpwd
  /var/www/mywebsite/gallery
  $ cd /etc
  $ mpwd
  /etc
  ```

  Note how non-matching directories (`/etc`) are not mangled.
- mount the remove directory at the same location locally, that is, execute sshfs for example like: `sshfs server:/var/www/mywebsite /var/www/mywebsite`. The directory obviously has to exist locally for that to work.

Comment: Thanks! This unfortunately won't work for me (I'm connecting to multiple servers… read more about my situation in the edited OP)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you know the path that is exported/mounted on your local machine? Wouldn't all paths under mount point be relative to the "exported" path?

```
sshfs [user@]host:[dir] mountpoint [options]
```

so if you are in [dir]/foo/bar then the pwd on the real host is /[dir]/foo/bar.

If you are mounting you home folder (default if no [dir]), and it is in a "custom" place, then finding out your home path may be done like so:

```
$ ssh flode echo \$HOME
/home/pvv/d/rakhmato
```

...then whatever I have at mountpoint/moo/hei is actually in /home/pvv/d/rakhmato/moo/hei

If the [dir] you are mounting is an alias to another folder (mount -o bind), then you can locate the original path by looking at the /etc/mtab file. Something like:

```
$ ssh localhost mount |grep '/media.*bind'
/mnt/media/media on /media type none (rw,bind)
/mnt/media/root-extension/usr/share/doc on /usr/share/doc type none (rw,bind)
```

...where localhost is the name of your server and '/media' is the [dir] that you mount via sshfs.

Comment: I don't have ssh access to [some] of the production servers, and some are just a shared hosting, actually (and I'm using SFTP to connect to them). I'll probably just write to support. Thank you though :)